# Node Js and Typescript call global function with parameters

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a logger function in **logger.ts**

```
export const Logger=(message:string, module?:string, method?:string)=>{
    console.log(`${module} ${message}`)
}
```

In **types/global.d.ts**

```
declare global {
    var Log: any;
}
export {}
```

In **index.ts**

```
import { Logger } from './src/utils/logger';
global.Log=Logger;
global.Log("Hello world");
```

It works without any problem. But in global.Log i can't see the parameters and intellisense not working.

How can I see parameters for global.Log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Intellisense is not working because the variable `Log` is of `any` type. Try defining global as below:

```
declare global {
    var Log: (message: string, module?: string, method?: string) => void;
}
export {};
```

Intellisense will need a specific type (not `any` or `unknown`) in order to suggest parameters.

Also, there is no need to prefix `Log` with `global` (i.e. `global.Log`) as `Log` is in the global context (accessible from anywhere), and it is not possible to use `global.Log` - global is not a variable.

Comment: Global object defined in Node Js and you can reach it from everywhere. [For details](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html)

Comment: If I use without global, I got an error *ReferenceError: Log is not defined*.

Comment: Finally I use global.Log when I assign the method. Otherwise I can directly use Log.